# Pop an index anywhere in an array

Tags: php

I want to be able to get a value from anywhere in my array, unset it, and shift the index so that my array indices are still in order.

Original array:

```
array:3 [
    0 => 'apple'
    1 => 'banana'
    2 => 'orange'
    3 => 'grapes'
]
```

Get the value of index 1, unset, and shift:

```
$val = 'banana';

array:2 [
    0 => 'apple'
    1 => 'orange'
    2 => 'grapes'
]
```

Is there a native PHP function similar to array_pop() or array_shift() that can do this?

Comment: Have you tried my answer? I should work perfectly in your case, let me know if it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_values` for that like as

```
$array = [
    0 => 'apple',
    1 => 'banana',
    2 => 'orange',
    3 => 'grapes'
];

unset($array[1]);

print_r(array_values($array));
```

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to do it using one function?

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant, is there a PHP function similar to array_pop() or array_shift() that can do the same only that I can get and unset a value anywhere in the array?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but why exactly it has to be one function?

Comment: I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything. But anyways, the code above works and I'm setting your answer as accepted. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

you will have to create a custom function

```
function removeAndreindex($array,$index)
 {
    unset($array[$index]);
    return array_values($array)
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
unset($array[array_search($val, $array)]);
```

The function array_search will return the index of the value `$val`, then you can remove it from the array by using unset() function.